# How to deploy react js build files in IIS manager

Tags: reactjs

I have generated my build files and configured in IIS by creating new site, and i have given my application pool has 'no code managed'. So apart from this I gave access to the folder for IUSR to in file explorer. Is it enough or am I missing something in configuration?

I have chosen the anonymous authentication in authentication under security tab in IIS manager

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.